# Internal server error while decoding a json file

Tags: php, mysql, json, internal-server-error

I'm opening a JSON file and decoding the content of it, so I can insert the content into my database using MySQL:

```
[{"publisher": "some publisher", "img": "url to image", "title": "some title", "platform": "some platform", "year": "2012", "genre": "some genre", "desc": "this is the description", "id": "1", "developer": "some developer"}]
```

This is just 1 one of the entries in the file. The JSON file contains more than 10000 of these. I'm getting internal server while using `json_decode($file)`. Reading the file and `var_dump($file)` works just fine. So my question is, is this a good JSON file? Or how can I decode and insert it in the database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to your server error log to find out more info? Can you try activating error reporting? It could be that you are hitting the memory limit.

Comment: Yes, I'm hitting the memory limit. Increasing the limit in php.ini will solve this right?

Comment: yes that will fix the problem or as my answer said use ini_set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that fragment of JSON.

You should look at the specific error message reported (either by running the PHP outside a web server, or by looking in the error logs for it). Internal Server Error just means "Something went wrong, an admin/developer should look at the logs".

Answer (score 4):

If the file is so big, it could be, that php runs out of memory or execution time, but as said before, start by looking in log files.

Comment: Well done repeating the comment where the OP states they ran out of memory.

Answer (score 3):

Again you need errors but unlike the others stating look at log file i do understand some times you can't certain Hosts for example,

To enable your script to show the error use

```
error_reporting(2047); 
ini_set("display_errors",1);
```

If your are getting a memory error use 
`ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');`

This should allow it if not or an error is throw because your calling ini_set you need to contact your server host and ask them to allow more memory

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error. I fixed it by changing my `json_decode($whatever)` code to `json_decode($whatever, TRUE)`. I hope this helps someone.